# InDesign to output PDF containing multiple copies in a single page of the same InDesign artwork

Tags: adobe-indesign

For example if I have a business card design done in InDesign and now I need to provide print ready PDF for printers containing multiple copies of the business card. How would you do that? Are there any specific tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InDesign doesn't do imposition (placing of pages on one output page in a particular order).
You have to buy/find a tool, a plugin. Like croptima dot com.
Or on this page, there's some interesting stuff:
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?l=6&s=5&o=desc&exc=19&cat=223&event=producthome

Alternatively do it by hand, or use a pdf imposition tool.
Succes!

Comment: No, I don't use them. But I think I would be googling on "open source pdf imposition tools"

Answer (score 3):

Do an export to PDF ( with any marks you need ). Get the file path. Open a text file and type in :

```
file
/myFile.pdf
/myFile.pdf
/myFile.pdf
/myFile.pdf
/myFile.pdf
/myFile.pdf
/myFile.pdf
…
```

Once that done. Go to Indesign, set a box that will host the pdf and run a data merge. You will get your imposition quite freely ;)

Loic

Comment: that looks promising. I don't know much about InDesign, but I created a frame and done data merge, but what I am getting is now multiple frames with the PDF file path text but not the actual PDF graphi. What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

My bad, you need to specify that you are placing images files with a trailing arobase :

```
@pdfs
"/myFile.pdf"
"/myFile.pdf"
"/myFile.pdf"
…
```

And specify the absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

How many cards do you need to layout ? If few, you could just flow the indd file into another document and duplicate boxes.

I didn't test but maybe you could draw a grid and point for the indesign file. Best scenario, if grid is selected, the file is flowed in every frame.

Loic

Comment: 20 per pages or more. I am looking for the way to automate it by scripting.